# Merge two tables withe condition R

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi here is a beginner question! I need some help regarding overwrite specific charter label, based on value from Class-column .

If the labels from Class-column says "Sport" with value from Sport-Class. Please see example below.

I tried to use `ifelse` statement:

```
DF$Class<-ifelse((DF$Class %in% "Sport"), DF$SportClass, DF$Class)
```

I have two columns, And my wanted output is "Column: Expectations"

```
ID:      Class:     SportClass:  |  (Expetions)
1        Movie      Hockey       |   Movie
2        Seriers    Fotboll      |   Series
3        Movie      Tennsi       |   Movie
4        Sport      Golf         |   Golf
```

Can somebody please assist me?

Comment: What happened when you run that? Was there an error? No error but nothing changed?

Comment: Also, I can't see the "merging" problem you mentioned in your title. Looks like a variable/column update based on another column.

Comment: i det get un numeric output, i think this is because my column was specified as a factor

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the correct column names of your dataframe and that your variables are not factors, because the levels don't match and your process breaks.

Using the following dataframe

```
DF = read.table(text = "
ID      Class     SportClass
1        Movie      Hockey    
2        Seriers    Fotboll     
3        Movie      Tennsi      
4        Sport      Golf         
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I can successfully update variable/column `Class`

```
# dataset before
DF

#   ID   Class SportClass
# 1  1   Movie     Hockey
# 2  2 Seriers    Fotboll
# 3  3   Movie     Tennsi
# 4  4   Sport       Golf

# update variable
DF$Class <- ifelse(DF$Class %in% "Sport", DF$SportClass, DF$Class)

# dataset after
DF

#   ID   Class SportClass
# 1  1   Movie     Hockey
# 2  2 Seriers    Fotboll
# 3  3   Movie     Tennsi
# 4  4    Golf       Golf
```

Note that you don't really parenthesis around `DF$Class %in% "Sport"` and that you can also use `DF$Class == "Sport"` in this case.